# Kendo UI Grid/Row Template

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-grid

I tried to put an image into Grid using Kendo UI. I had a problem with `columns.Bound(c => c.ProductPhotoID)`, when I comment `columns.Bound(c => c.ProductPhotoID)` the Grid can be edit, but when uncomment it the Grid cannot edit anymore. I have no idea with this.

```
@model IEnumerable<SubCateViewModel>
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
.Name("Grid")
.Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(c => c.ProductSubcategoryID).Width(140);
        columns.Bound(c => c.ProductCategoryID).Width(140);
        columns.Bound(c => c.NameofBike).Width(190);
        columns.Bound(c => c.Name).Width(190);
        columns.Bound(c => c.ProductPhotoID).Width(50).ClientTemplate("<img alt='<#= PictureUrl #>' src'"
            + Url.Content("~/GetImage.ashx?ID=@bike.ProductProductPhotoes.FirstOrDefault().ProductPhotoID")
            + "#= PictureUrl#.jpq'/>").Title("Picture");
        columns.Bound(c => c.isSelected).Width(120);
    })
```

Could anybody tell me what happened with `columns.Bound(c => c.ProductPhotoID)`, and help me in advanced to put an image in the Grid. I really appreciate that! I follow this [link](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/grid/rowtemplate.html).

Comment: The example that you have used is using ClientRowTemplate. Did you try using that?

Comment: read this link it's just example i hope it help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22222272/kendo-file-upload-control-not-working-in-edit-mode/22222718#22222718

Comment: @Nilesh I did using ClientRowTemplate, it didn't work. Could you tell me how to do that?

Comment: @Jaimin Can I put my `Controller` for more information ?

Comment: @TrungPham yes you can.